# Looking for HP Pavilion dv2-1117e XP drivers

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dv2-1117e entertainment notebook. I have installed Windows XP, but I don't have drivers for the video, audio, or WLAN. Where can I find them?

Comment: FYI - answers to your question will be posted here, not sent to your email. I have edited your email address out of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP is not fully supported on this machine and the drivers are unavailble directly from HP, you will have to look for drivers on the chipset company websites such as:

[Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw), [Intel](http://www.intel.com), [Synaptics](http://www.synaptics.com/) etc.

As for graphics, take a look at [LaptopVideo2Go](http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/) (This site is mainly for Nvidia, but take a look at forums.)

All this being said, Vista is fine! Don't believe the hype of how bad it is, you shouldn't have problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

See the Third post in this link

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Operating-systems-and-software/General-XP-Downgrade-Guide-for-HP-Laptops/td-p/83267

3 .   Difficult Models

For NEW notebook consumer models e.i. Presario, Pavilion, and HDX models are difficult to downgrade. It is possible task but needs many efforts.

Difficult models are CQ40, CQ35, CQ45, CQ61  Presario models, dv2, dv3, dv4, dv5, dv6, dv7  Pavilion models and all HDX models